# Derivative of a arctan

Tags: derivatives

I am not sure on how to even start, I know how to do simpler derivative but not a complex one like this.

I need to find $\frac{d(x^2 arctan(5x))}{dx}$

Comment: Use the [product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule), and the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} \arctan(kx)=\frac{k}{k^2x^2+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go. You know that $\arctan'(x) = \frac1{1+x^2}$. Then the derivative of 
$$
\arctan(5x)
$$
is $$
5\frac1{1+(5x)^2}
$$
Then use the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle \frac{d(x^2\arctan(5x))}{dx}=\\2x\arctan(5x)+x^2\left(\frac{5}{1+25x^2}\right)$$
by product rule and derivative of $\arctan$ function.